# TxReceipt Status fail sending ETH to Contract on Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, crowdsale, openzeppelin

I am sending ETH on Rinkeby network from my wallet in Metamask to a contract that has been deployed on Rinkeby. This is a crowdsale contract [based on Open Zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol).

However when I check the [transaction details on Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x3466ac18fb3a6707fc99e186bf6519e1fd95a15c19a66b55d3789a4922ecbf3d), I get the following error:

> TxReceipt Status: Fail

How do I find out the problem?

---

### Update

Metamask's suggested gas amount is always unusually high when the transaction is to fail...

ETH was sent to the `TestTokenSale.sol` contract.

**Rinkeby transaction:** [0xbbcff212c72e201412a3c4f4304d13e517212b793f04ae597399d2f375052b36](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xbbcff212c72e201412a3c4f4304d13e517212b793f04ae597399d2f375052b36)

**geth debug.traceTransaction:** [[Gist]](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7f5175cc9a48a0fdf8b63168227c393)

The `TestToken.sol` is first deployed, followed by `TestTokenSale.sol`

**TestToken.sol**

Constructor Arguments: `'qwe', 'qwe, 'qwe', 123`

```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

  import "./libs/zeppelin/token/MintableToken.sol";

  contract TestToken is MintableToken {

     string public name;
     string public symbol;
     uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
     string public constant version = "1.0";

     string public location;
     uint8 public power;

     uint256 public constant tokenUnit = 10 ** 18;

     function TestToken(string _name, string _symbol, string _location, uint8 _power) {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;

        location = _location;
        power = _power;
     }
  }
```

**TestTokenSale.sol**

Constructor arguments: `1520889758, 1530889758, 500, 10000000, 0xcede48d8ac162d1b08ed9419010de3c99f2cfdd6, 0x37b925b6c72cc313bea41b95629b74478d9d442b`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol";
import './TestToken.sol';



contract TestTokenSale is CappedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale {

  address public tokenContractAddress;

  function TestTokenSale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _cap, address _wallet, address _tokenContractAddress)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    FinalizableCrowdsale()
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
  {
    tokenContractAddress = _tokenContractAddress;
  }

  function createTokenContract(address tokenContractAddress) internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return TestToken(tokenContractAddress);
  }


  function finalization() internal {
  }

}
```

---

### Update 2

ETH send to `TestTokenSale.sol` still fails...

**Tx:** [0x640771750ded31c0ef817d1e0df3a1ec16c186fd353a6034dd1799af26e486ed](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x640771750ded31c0ef817d1e0df3a1ec16c186fd353a6034dd1799af26e486ed)

**TestTokenSale.sol**

Constructor arguments: `1511235849, 1530889758, 500, 10000000, 0xcede48d8ac162d1b08ed9419010de3c99f2cfdd6, 0x47a27fb4722f293b7ab499ef910d1f2ca78b94b6`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol";
import './TestToken.sol';



contract TestTokenSale is CappedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale {

  address public tokenContractAddress;

  function TestTokenSale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _cap, address _wallet, address _tokenContractAddress)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    FinalizableCrowdsale()
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
  {
    token = TestToken(_tokenContractAddress);
  }

  function finalization() internal {
  }

}
```

---

### Update 3

Tx: [0x561f9cb4630905c2bb1391db3d3d1afd3b29cc454b238b25dbc3372f19c4a274](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x561f9cb4630905c2bb1391db3d3d1afd3b29cc454b238b25dbc3372f19c4a274)

ETH sends **successfully** to `TestTokenSale.sol` contract only if `Crowdsale.sol` was edited to comment out `require(validPurchase())` :

**Code works**

```
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    // require(validPurchase());
    ...
```

**Code fails**

ETH send will fail if I dont comment out that line, but instead set `validPurchase()` to `return true`:

```
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    require(validPurchase());
    ...


  function validPurchase() internal constant returns (bool) {
    return true;
    // bool withinPeriod = now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
    // bool nonZeroPurchase = msg.value != 0;
    // return withinPeriod && nonZeroPurchase;
  }
```

**Code works!!!**

```
  // low level token purchase function
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    require(now >= startTime);
    require(now <= endTime);
    require(msg.value != 0);
    // require(validPurchase());
```

Shouldnt `require(validPurchase())` not throw any errors if `validPurchase()` returns `true`?

Why does it work if the 3 conditions are moved from `validPurchase()` out to `buyTokens`, but dont work when they are inside `validPurchase()~?

What's happening here?

Comment: Do you have the contract code? From the geth trace it is making a revert after some checks. And it is early on the execution, likely one of the require/assert has failed. Without the source code is hard to say anything more.

Comment: @Ismael I have posted the contract code in the question, and tried deploying this again, so please refer to the latest transaction hash `0xbbcff212c72e201412a3c4f4304d13e517212b793f04ae597399d2f375052b36`. Do you see anything wrong with the contract code?

Comment: Your contract https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x6229d9c34eb7e722dd693a9dd52cb7ff5392e0af has parameters startTime: 0x5a139137 (1511231799) 2017-11-21T02:36:39+00:00, endTime: 0x5b3f861e (1530889758) 2018-07-06T15:09:18+00:00. Your tx was processed at (1511232006) 2017-11-21T02:40:06+00:00. So that appears to be ok.

Comment: The problem is your constructor calls `Crowdsale()` which in turn will call `createTokenContract()` which will return `TestToken(tokenContractAddress)`, but it will return 0x0, because `tokenContractAddress` is not yet initialzed. Drop variable `tokenContractAddress` and assign directly in your constructor `token = MintableToken(_tokenContractAddress);`

Comment: @Ismael Should I still override `createTokenContract`?

Comment: @Ismael Added **Update 2** to the question based on your suggestion. Unfortunately the sending of ETH to the contract still fails...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you more, try debugging with remix or testrpc. From the geth trace last two transaction are exactly the same. Note that `mint()` called from `buyTokens()` but it is `onlyOwner` so you have to set the crowdsale as token's owner, but I do not think that is the error here.

Comment: @Ismael I changed the ownership and it looks like its almost working! To get it to work 100%, I had to comment out `require(validPurchase());` in the function `buyTokens` of `Crowdsale.sol`... Editing `validPurchase` to just `return true` also caused the ETH send to fail... Thats so strange?

Comment: @Ismael Updated post with **Update 3** to better explain the previous comment... I'm so confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had some of the same problems as you did. What we figured out was the following:

1. `startTime` and `endTime` must be set so that when you call the
   contract, you are in fact buying tokens when the sale is open. We
   added a `hasStarted()` method and called both this and the
   `hasEnded()` method to make sure that we were in fact within the
   sale period.
2. The `startTime` must be in the future. If it is not, nothing will work. This is why we add 90 seconds to the current timestamp.
3. The data types in the migration script is really important.

   - You cannot just send inn `accounts[0]` in the constructor -
     the address needs to be a string when it is called from the migration file.
   - You cannot send in a normal number (like `25`) as the `rate` - it needs to be a `web3.BigNumber(25)`.

For reference, here is our migration file:
**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
var MyTokenCrowdsale = artifacts.require("MyTokenCrowdsale");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const start = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp + 90;
  const end = start + (86400 * 30); // 30 days
  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(25);
  wallet = accounts[1].toString();
  deployer.deploy(MyTokenCrowdsale, start, end, rate, wallet);
};
```

Comment: Working! Why did you pass a `web3.BigNumber` instead of a regular `int` for the `rate`

Comment: Because the constructor expects the number to be a `web3.BigNumber` and not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the contract code one can see that the contract accepts Ether only during the period in which the token sale takes place. If you send ether outside of this period, the contract will interrupt execution and return your ether (i.e. what is left after paying the gas required to execute the contract up to this point).

The period of the token sale is set when creating the contract by parameters `_starttime` and `_endtime` of the constructor. I did not look at contract storage to verify which values were set for `_starttime` and `_endtime`. However, you could start trouble shooting at this point and check that reasonable values for `_starttime` and `_endtime` were set at contract creation.

Comment: I checked that the time I sent the ETH to contract was between the `_startTime` and `_endTime`. But the transaction still failed...

Comment: For example, `_startTime=1511127652`, `_endTime=1530889758`, and the time I sent the ETH to the contract was after `1511127656` according to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: So that should be ok. You can try to debug the code, using Remix, for example. Or take out line by line from the buyTokens-function, deploy the contract every time you took out a line and find out in which line things are not running as they should. A little tedious, though...

Comment: Great approach! I commented out each line of code one by one starting from the last line in the `buyTokens` function, and `token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);` seem to be the line causing the ETH send to fail!

Comment: The `MintableToken` was deployed separately from the `Crowdsale` contract, I wonder if this causes a problem with the `mint` function having the modifiers `onlyOwner canMint`, maybe the crowdsale contract is not the owner of the `MintableToken`?

Comment: I ran `transferOwnership` to transfer ownership of the `MintableToken` to the `Crowdsale` contract,and verified that the `owner` property of `MintableToken` is the address of the `Crowdsale` contract. However `token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);` is still causing the sending of ETH to `Crowdsale` contract to fail...